# download and display the google trends csv file using php

Tags: php, api

i been trying to download the csv file from this link
http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en-US&q=nba&geo=US&date=today%207-d&cmpt=q&content=1&export=1

but failed again and again, i tried most of the codes available online and here on stackexchange also, but none got me working properly, if anyone know how to achieve it, please share it here, as most of us get it useful.

i also got some advice that it uses cookies these days.
another advice is one should use the google account to login and then try, but unfortunately i failed both.

or else i may be going wrong.
the one valid trial i did was here.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email=myemail@gmail.com&Passwd=mypass&service=trends&source=test-test-v1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/var/www/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/cookies.txt');

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=nba&geo=US&date=today%207-d&cmpt=q");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: so no one is willing to answer this question for me.???

Answer (score 1):

### Use file_get_contents , I don't think their is need to use curl .

**for example**

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $page;
```

Comment: hi, i already tried it, and it works for few iterations only, once done, it gets error saying your quota limit is reached